# Select statement using WHERE x IN (SELECT ...)

Tags: sql, mysql, select, join

I have two tables:

```
[ product_to_category
---------------------
product_id
category_id


[ category
---------------------
category_id
parent_id
```

I need to get all product_id's with a category.parent_id of '39'. Here's what I'm trying, but it's returning empty when there are at least a few hundred:

```
SELECT
product_id
FROM
product_to_category
WHERE
category_id IN (
SELECT parent_id FROM category WHERE parent_id = '39'
)
```

Is what I'm trying to do here possible?

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772609/procedurally-transform-subquery-into-join

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it:

> SELECT product_id FROM
>   product_to_category INNER JOIN
>   category ON
>   product_to_category.category_id =
>   category.category_id AND
>   category.parent_id = 39

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_to_category p2c
   Join category c 
      On c.category_id = p2c.category_id
Where parent_id = '39'
```

What you were doing wrong in your query was:

```
 SELECT product_id
 FROM product_to_category
 WHERE category_id IN 
     (SELECT category_id   -- THIS IS WHERE YOUR SQL WAS INCORRECT
      FROM category WHERE parent_id = '39')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id from product_to_category as ptc
inner join category as c
    on ptc.category_id = c.parent_id
where c.parent_id = 39
```